# Unable to connect to MongoLab exception: login failed

Tags: mongodb, heroku, deployment, mlab

I try deploy my app Node.js + MongoDB.

1. I deployed my app on Heroku. [Added add-ons Mongolab to app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqh0p.png).
2. Opened my data base and create new user name: dima; password: *** (Add database user).
3. Then I try to connect to the DB:

   My console:

   mongo ds039135.mongolab.com:39135/heroku_xkbthxdx -u dima -p ***

   MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9

   connecting to: ds039135.mongolab.com:39135/heroku_xkbthxdx

   Fri Feb 19 19:26:50.181 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:228

   exception: login failed

What is missing in this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mongo` shell version is 2.4.9. Currently all MongoLab Sandbox databases are version 3.

Upgrade your `mongo` shell to 3.x.y - preferably matching major release versions between client and server, MongoDB can be sensitive to major version discrepancies. Eg: Use 3.0.x shell with 3.0.x server, 2.6.x shell with 2.6.x server, etc.

Edit - adding the "why": Starting with 3.0, the default authentication mechanism is SCRAM-SHA-1, which the 2.4 `mongo` shell does not support, hence the failed authentication.

Answer (score 1):

And then, if you have any problem with your user/pass, you can get your database username and password with:

`heroku config | grep MONGODB_URI`

The response is in the form of:

`MONGOLAB_URI: mongodb://username:password@mlab.com:12345/db`